# Conditional branch name in imageRepository in Azure yaml file

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

In Azure yaml file defining pipeline. I would like imageRepository contain name of the branch from which pipeline was executed. For example,

if I run from `branch_A`, I would like to have `imageRepository:branch_A_image`

if I run from `branch_B`, I would like to have `imageRepository:branch_B_image`

How does this conditional statement in yaml would look like? I found different bits and pieces, but could not find everything `'Build.SourceBranch'`???

My ultimate goal is to have different container images for different branches. I am planning to trigger pipeline manually for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are searching the `Build.SourceBranch` and `Build.SourceBranchName`. You can get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services). It looks like this:

[image]

So the right image name should be set like this:

```
imageRegistory:$(Build.SourceBranchName)
```

Comment: This is awesome! Do you know if I can concatenate something to it? Something like `$(Build.SourceBranchName)_contaner`

Comment: @user1700890 Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it solves your problem please accept it.

Comment: @user1700890 What's the reason that you do not accept it when it solves your problem? It's simple to mark it.